# Custom Module Layout Not Working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module

I added custom link in header tab example chat, if i click this link move one custom form, but, its only show only 1column layout, form not showing. what I miss this code.

This is my layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

 <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-  instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="ChennaiBox\Chat\Block\ChatBlock" template="ChennaiBox_Chat::ChatForm.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>

  </body>
  </page>
```

This is My Block:

```
 <?php

  namespace ChennaiBox\Chat\Block;
  class ChatBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template  
   {


   }
```

This is Template File:

```
 <?php?>
<h1>Chat</h1>
```

This is my default.xml layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>

  <page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
     <body>
      <move element="Chat_link" destination="header.links"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="Chat_link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Chat</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">chennaibox/livechat/livechat</argument>
            </arguments>
           </block> 
 </referenceContainer>
 </body>
 </page>
```

This is my controller:

```
 <?php

 namespace ChennaiBox\Chat\Controller\LiveChat;
  class LiveChat extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
   {

 protected $resultPageFactory;

 public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $page)
    {
      parent::__construct($context);
      $this->resultPageFactory = $page;       
    }
public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    return $resultPage;

   //echo "This is my test";
}
```

}

I need to print "Chat"  word in layout, but its only show 1 column layout what i miss. suggest me how to do this...

Comment: you have to define layout="3columns" in your xml file at first you have displayed

Comment: yes, my layout file working , then only show chat link  in header panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just **3columns** in your layout file instead of 1column.

Try below code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

  <page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
     <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="ChennaiBox\Chat\Block\ChatBlock" name="Chat_link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Chat</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">chennaibox/livechat/livechat</argument>
            </arguments>
           </block> 

      <move element="Chat_link" destination="header.links"/>
 </referenceContainer>
 </body>
 </page>
```

inside your block,

`ChatBlock.php` file,

```
namespace ChennaiBox\Chat\Block;

/**
 * Class Link
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.DepthOfInheritance)
 */
class ChatBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
    protected $_template = 'ChennaiBox_Chat::ChatForm.phtml';    



    public function getLabel()
    {        
        return __('Chat');
    }
}
```

Comment: My layout is working but, my template not working for me , it show, invalid template file.

Comment: where you have define your template path?

Comment: My default.xml file, i wrote in my custom theme file, my custom theme extends luma theme, but, my bllock and template content i wrote cutom module, they have any problem... but, i mentioned path of block in default.xml file.

Comment: plz show your default.xml file

Comment: I added Above in the list " default.xml" file...

Comment: plz set <block class="ChennaiBox\Chat\Block\ChatBlock" template="ChennaiBox_Chat::ChatForm.phtml" name="chennaiboxchat"/>

Comment: for now, also not working for me.. only show lcoumn layout...not a template content

Comment: i have updated my answer follow above code